# Partial clone of virtual machine in VMware

Tags: vmware-esxi, virtual-machines, vmware-vsphere, clone

I have to clone a virtual machine hosted by a VMware ESXi server. In particular, the virtual machine has three disks: is there a way to clone the machine not entirely? In other words, I don't care about two disks of three, I want the same machine, but only with one disk. Is it possible?

Thanks in advance.

Andrea

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can. While finishing the process select the option

> Edit virtual hardware

[image: EDIT]

Then you can remove the HDD's.

[image: Edit1]

Comment: I'm using vSphere client connected to ESXi host and I don't have the "Clone Virtual Machine" operation you mentioned. I can select the export option, to create OVA/OVF files, and then I can't choose disks to remove. What software are you using for it?

Comment: You have to clone using vCenter server

Comment: If you're exporting the VM to an OVA/OVF then simply remove the disks when you provision a new VM from the OVA/OVF.

Comment: Solved using VMware vCenter Converter Standalone.